# 4kvideodownloader launcher doesn't start

Tags: glibc, download-manager

About 6 months ago 4kvideodownloader just stopped working. When I try to start the app it shows up on the launcher for 5 seconds and it looks like it's about to open, but it disappears without having ever opened.

I tried uninstalling and installing the newest version from their site (`.deb` file), but the problem remains to this day.

I think this started when I upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. I should also mention that I have the exact same problem on my other Ubuntu 16.04 computer as well. I've googled the issue and I've concluded it must have to do with Ubuntu and not the app itself.

When I write `4kvideodownloader` in the Terminal I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5)
/usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5)
/usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/libQt5Gui.so.5)
/usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/libQt5Core.so.5)
/usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/libavcodec.so.58)
/usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/libavformat.so.58)
/usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/4kvideodownloader-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/4kvideodownloader/libmp3lame.so.0)
```

Comment: What do you get when running it from terminal ? (any error messages ?) . If any, please add them to your post .

Comment: Of course . Open your terminal via menu or Ctrl+Alt+T then type "4kvideodownloader" and press enter . Post the errors it prints.

Comment: Oh , the problem is that it's trying to use your system's Glibc ( which is the library (equivalent to windows DLLs ) that almost every program in linux requires it in order to run ) but other libraries in the program itself is much newer and wants a newer glibc version. I think this is because they haven't released that for ubuntu 16.04. Maybe 18 or 20. They haven't mentioned it in their download page. But you can download the [portable version](https://dl.4kdownload.com/app/4kvideodownloader_4.12.4_amd64.tar.bz2?source=website) to solve this .

Comment: Thank you, Parsa! 
I googled the error msg from the Terminal and found a forum where they discuss this exact problem. They talked about how installing an older version of the program solves the issue. And it did!

Comment: It's absolutely fine (and very much encouraged) to [self-answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer), but adding the solution to the question itself is not. Please undelete your answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

An error like this

```
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by libavformat.so.58)
```

is caused when you want to execute a program which requires a different (in this case newer) version of some libraries ( in this case `libc` and `libm` ) and that is not available in your system. You can solve this by downloading the [portable version](https://www.4kdownload.com/downloads) which have all of the needed libraries in its package.( Note the difference in size : 67.1 MB vs 82.9 MB )

Looks like they haven't released that package for 16.04 .Maybe 18 or 20.